# ¿Guardar objetos en array en swift?

Tags: array, swift, clase, objeto

La idea es ingreasar datos de una persona y despues que se guarden en una array para despues poder accederlos y modificarlos o buscarlos pero no comprendo como guardar los objetos creados de la clase en un array en swift.La idea es que se guarden al finalizar la funcion de ingresar.No estoy utilizando xcode,esto solo es un programa que funciona desde la consola.Tampoco se si la forma en que declare la clase es la mas correcta

```
class Clientes {
 
    var nombre:String
    var compañia: String
    var telefono: String
    var correo: String
    var fechaRegistro: String
    

    init(nombre:String, compañia:String,telefono:String,correo:String,fechaRegistro:String) {
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.compañia = compañia
        self.telefono = telefono
        self.correo = correo
        self.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro
    }


}
 func ingresar() {
      print("ESCRIBE TU NOMBRE")
let nombreCliente=readLine()
 print("ESCRIBE TU COMPAÑIA")
let compañiaCliente=readLine()
 print("ESCRIBE TU TELEFONO")
let telefonoCliente=readLine()
 print("ESCRIBE TU CORREO")
let correoCliente=readLine()
 print("ESCRIBE LA FECHA")
let fechaRegistro=readLine()

    }

func menu()
{

  while true {
    print("MENU")
    print("1-INGRESAR")
    print("2-MODIFICAR")
    print("3-ELIMINAR")
    print("4-BUSCAR")
    print("5-MOSTRAR TODO")
let opciones = readLine()
   if opciones == "1"
   {
     ingresar()
   }
   if(opciones == "2")
    {
      print(opciones!)
    }
  
}
}
menu()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías tener el array inicializado. De esta forma defines que va a guardar datos de tipo Cliente y que es un array. Lo inicializas vacío.

```
var listado: [Clientes] = []
```

Una vez que has recogido los datos tendrás que crear el elemento Clientes, tienes los datos y tienes la clase creada, así que después de recoger los datos lo creas y lo añades.

```
let cliente = Cliente(nombre: nombreCliente, compañia: compañiaCliente, telefono: telefonoCliente, correo: correoCliente, fechaRegistro: fechaRegistro)
self.listado.append(cliente)
```